# How to structure this React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and would appreciate advice on how to structure my application in a Reacty way.

I am building an interactive with the following components:

```
<text input 1> - when user inputs data here, chart 1 updates
<chart 1>
<text input 2> - when user inputs data here, chart 2 updates
<chart 2>
<text input 3> - when user inputs data here, chart 3 updates
<chart 3>
<final chart> - should render automatically when user has input data into all three text fields
```

My initial thought was to create a `TextChart` child component:

```
class TextChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: this.element.value });
    this.renderChart();
  }

  renderChart() {
    // creates chart based on props.data and state.value
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" ref={el => this.element = el} />
        <input type="submit" value="Show" />
      </form>
      <svg id={this.props.name} width="500" height="300"></svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And then call this three times, initialised with the data for each chart:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <WealthInput name="textchart1" data=data />,
  document.getElementById('textchart1')
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <WealthInput name="textchart2" data=data />,
  document.getElementById('textchart2')
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <WealthInput name="textchart3" data=data />,
  document.getElementById('textchart3')
);
```

But now I am having problems working out how to create the final chart. It depends on the values set in each `TextChart` component, and should render automatically when all three have been set. However, these values are set in the local state of the child components, rather than the global props of the app.

It seems that in React it's not generally possible to set global props inside a child component.

How should I create my final chart? It should render automatically once all three values are set in the TextChart.

Comment: Read [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html), if you haven't already. The problem is that you're storing the data in the child state - if you want state to be shared by components, lift it up into their closest common ancestor.

Comment: So in other words, you need a shared parent component for both your `WealthInput` instances *and* your charts. Then you can just pass data and callbacks down as props.

Comment: finalchart is dependent on the values of those 3 input fields?

Comment: @MayankShukla yes it is dependent on those 3 fields.

Comment: @JoeClay reading the linked React articles was useful, thanks!